# Change every bundle item price on addtocart

Tags: product, cart, magento-1, price, bundle

I want to change each and every selected bundle items price on addtocart

How can I do this.

At present I am doing like below :

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
if ($item->getParentItem()) {$item = $item->getParentItem();}
$item->setCustomPrice(10);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice(10);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

By doing above, it only change Parent Bundle product Price.

Please check screenshot :

[image]

So is there any posibility to change price of bundle items with custom price which will display properly even after order place in order view page.
I have go through the code and find that "Bundle Items's" price are saved in infobuyrequest.

```
$sel_bundle_options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
$sel_bundle_options['bundle_options'];
```

So is it possible to change price directly into that ?
But after placing an order if we check on order view pages,it will display.

Comment: I would recommend using a total model instead of wasting time on editing the buyrequest.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Can someone Please help on this issue?

Comment: @MagentoTeam please look my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do below code while adding product to the cart.

```
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$price = '';
foreach ($cart as $i)
{
  if ($i->getId() == '') // Dont getting id for currently adding bundle item.
  {  
     $options = $i->getOptions();
     foreach ($options as $option)
     {
        if ($option->getCode() == 'bundle_selection_attributes')
        {
           $unserialized = unserialize($option->getValue());
           $price = 10; // YOUR CUSTOM PRICE
           $unserialized['price'] = number_format($price, 2, '.', ',');
           $option->setValue(serialize($unserialized));
        }
     }
     try
     {
        $i->setOptions($options)->save();
     }
     catch (Exception $e)
     {}
     $i->setCustomPrice($price);
     $i->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
  }
}
```